# "Feed on" or "feed with"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

Is it correct to say, for example: *"She fed him on lamb"* as well as *"She fed him with lamb"*? 
Omitting the preposition and simply leaving the sentence as *"She fed him lamb"* sounds more acceptable to me, but I'm interested in the difference in meaning using either one preposition or the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*"She fed him lamb"* is the best way to say that she gave him a meal of lamb. The phrase *"She fed him on lamb"* implies a steady diet of lamb that she's feeding him. The phrase *"She fed him with lamb"* doesn't sound as correct as just leaving out the preposition entirely.

> How did her dog get so big? She fed him on lamb (habitually).
>
> What did she feed the dog for dinner? She fed him lamb (just once).

Answer (score 0):

The eater "feeds on" something.  Polar bears *feed on* seals.

The person who gives someone (or an animal) food, "feeds" the person (or the animal).  She *fed* the child porridge.  He *feeds* the pigeons (with)  breadcrumbs.

In your "fed him on lamb" example, you're conflating these verbs.